# Encrypt PDFs in python

Tags: python, pdf, encryption

Is there a possible and way to encrypt PDF-Files in python?
One possibility is to zip the PDFs but is there another ? 
Thanks for your help 
regards
Felix

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/):

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

writer = PdfWriter()
writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
writer.encrypt("password")

with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file:
    writer.write(out_file)
```

For more information, check out the `PdfWriter` [docs](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfWriter.html#pypdf.PdfWriter.encrypt).

Comment: PikePDF (presented below) seems to offer much stronger encryption.

Comment: Actully it's making two different pdfs', input.pdf plus output.pdf, is there any way to dairecyly encrypt input.pdf insted of creating new output.pdf

Answer (score 9):

PikePdf which is python's adaptation of QPDF, is by far the better option. This is especially helpful if you have a file that has text in languages other than English.

```
import pikepdf
pdf = pikepdf.Pdf.open(path/to/file)    
pdf.save('output_filename.pdf', encryption=pikepdf.Encryption(owner=password, user=password, R=4)) 
# you can change the R from 4 to 6 for 256 aes encryption
pdf.close()
```

Comment: use ```import pikepdf``` instead ```from pikepdf import Pdf```
otherwise ```encryption=pikepdf.Encryption``` will throw ```NameError: name 'pikepdf' is not defined```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/)

```
import pypdf
# Create reader and writer object
reader = pypdf.PdfReader("input.pdf")
writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()
# Add all pages to writer (accepted answer results into blank pages)
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)
# Encrypt with your password
writer.encrypt('password')
# Write it to an output file. (you can delete unencrypted version now)
with open('encrypted_output.pdf', 'wb') as resultPdf:
    writer.write(resultPdf)
```

Comment: Any comment on the resulting warning: `UserWarning: pypdf only implements RC4 encryption so far. The RC4 algorithm is insecure. Either use a library that supports AES for encryption or put the PDF in an encrypted container, for example an encrypted ZIP file.`

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend the pyAesCrypt module.
It is based on the Cryptography module which is written partly in C.
The module is quite fast, especially in high spec computers.
You can expect a 12 second encryption of a 3 Gb file on higher end computers, so It really is fast though not the best one.

**One liner for encryptions and Decryptions are:**

```
import pyAesCrypt
```

**Encrypting:**

```
pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(inputfile, outputfile, password, bufferSize)
```

**Decrypting:**

```
pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(inputfile, outputfile, password, bufferSize)
```

Since this is not the full explanation I would recommend to fully read the documentation as It is not really long.
You can find it here: https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Aspose.PDF Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/pdf/python), it is a rest API solution. You can use cloud storage of your choice from Amazon S3, DropBox, Google Drive Storage, Google Cloud Storage, Windows Azure Storage, FTP Storage and Aspose Cloud Storage.

The cryptoAlgorithm takes the follwing possible values

- RC4x40:  RC4 with key length 40
- RC4x128: RC4 with key length 128
- AESx128: AES with key length 128
- AESx256: AES with key length 256

```
import os
import base64
import asposepdfcloud
from asposepdfcloud.apis.pdf_api import PdfApi
from shutil import copyfile

# Get Client key and Client ID from https://cloud.aspose.com
pdf_api_client = asposepdfcloud.api_client.ApiClient(
    app_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    app_sid='xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx')

pdf_api = PdfApi(pdf_api_client)
temp_folder="Temp"

#upload PDF file to storage
data_file = "C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf"
remote_name= "02_pages.pdf"
pdf_api.upload_file(remote_name,data_file)

out_path = "EncryptedPDF.pdf"

user_password_encoded = base64.b64encode(b'user $^Password!&')
owner_password_encoded = base64.b64encode(b'owner\//? $12^Password!&')

#Encrypte PDF document
response = pdf_api.put_encrypt_document(temp_folder + '/' + out_path, user_password_encoded, owner_password_encoded, asposepdfcloud.models.CryptoAlgorithm.AESX128, file = remote_name)

#download PDF file from storage
response_download = pdf_api.download_file(temp_folder + '/' + out_path)
copyfile(response_download, 'C:/Temp/' + out_path)
print(response)
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of sending confidential data to a random web service