# Encrypt a PDF File in 256 Bit AES Encryption Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt files in 256 bit AES Encryption, cause screw Adobe for their $15 a month to do this...

I found the library [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) however this will only allow up to 128 bit with the following code:

```py
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

out = PdfFileWriter()

file = PdfFileReader("input.pdf")

num = file.numPages

for i in range(num):
    page = file.getPage(i)
    out.addPage(page)

password = "password"

out.encrypt(password, password, True)

with open("out.pdf", "wb") as f:
    out.write(f)
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256) post however it does not deal with the pdf aspect to my knowledge, just encrypts the bytes. I would ideally want an output, password protected PDF that can be opened in acrobat or another reader, just without having to pay for the privilege of encrypting them.

I wondered if anyone was aware of, or knew how to change this module, a way to get 256 bit password encryption? Thanks!

Comment: This specific answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545360/7941251 may help

Comment: It works, thanks so much! Should have read down...